# Dynamic horizontal scrolling shadows

Tags: jquery

How would I detect wether a horizontal scroll bar is at the end.

I have got this far with adding horizontal scrolling shadows:
http://codepen.io/hugo/pen/kCveF

but I would like to remove the class ".shadow-middle" and add the class".shadow-left" when the scroll bar gets to the end.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to get the window size when the page loads and then set a `scrollLeft()`  if statement that went something like if scrollLeft equals window width remove shadow middle and add shadow left.

I forked your project on codepen and then wrote the javaScript I was explaining. here is the [pen](http://codepen.io/kqlambert/pen/nkbCy)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the width of the container and compare it with the scrollLeft, switching the classes when they are the same on scroll